# Reasons for IPC control in Linux

Tags: linux, ipc

Linux OS has several IPC mechanisms like named pipes, sys V, d-bus etc. Each of these mechanisms always has senders and receivers of IPC; each mechanism uses some way to control IPC between senders and receivers.

I want to ask what are the primary reasons OS developers want to provide control over IPC ?

Is it because the sender / receiver cannot handle a IPC from some random process, may be because they don't have proper input validation in place OR just don't want to provide service to just any one ?

Comment: The same reason for any other kind of access control: to prevent unauthorized users from interfering with other applications.

Comment: But on Linux ... if running on the same user account .. all apps will run my uid, then how can reasoning be done in terms on users ? Within the same account, there exists some IPC control as well right ?

Comment: I'm not sure what controls you're talking about. I'm just talking about access control between different accounts.

Comment: What I meant was .. within the same account .. is there any access control being done wrt IPC between different processes ?

Comment: Please update your question, showing the kinds of controls you're asking about. Then you can request that it be reopened, and if the improvements are sufficient it probably will be.